# printing stdout pipe of sub processes ignore last lines

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to run a sub processes and watching his stdout until I find desirable string.
this is my code:

```py
    def waitForAppOutput(proc, word):
        for stdout_line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, b''):
           print stdout_line
           if word in stdout_line.rstrip():
              return;

    p = Popen(["./app.sh"], shell=True, stdin=PIPE ,stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    waitForAppOutput(p,"done!")
```

the issue here is that for some reason the function `waitForAppOutput` stop printing stdout few lines before the "done!" which is the last line that should appear in the stdout . I assume `iter(proc.stdout.readline, b'')` is blocking and `readline` is not able to read the last lines of the stdout.

any idea what is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

You have a misspelling: it should be `waitForAppOutput` instead of `waitForAppOutout`. How does this even run at all? And when you are invoking a command using a shell, you should not be passing an array of strings but rather one single string.

Normally one should use the `communicate` method on the return subprocess object from the `Popen` call to prevent potential deadlocks (which seems to be what you are experiencing). This returns a tuple: `(stdout, stderr)`, the `stdout` and `stderr` output strings:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


def waitForAppOutput(stdout_lines, word):
    for stdout_line in stdout_lines:
       print stdout_line
       if word in stdout_line.rstrip():
          return;

p = Popen("./app.sh", shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
expected_input = "command line 1\ncommand line 2\n"
stdout, stderr = p.communicate(expected_input)
stdout_lines = stdout.splitlines()
waitForAppOutput(stdout_lines, "done!")
```

The only issue is if the output strings are large (whatever your definition of *large* might be), for it might be memory-inefficient or even prohibitive to read the entire output into memory. If this is your situation, then I would try to avoid the deadlock by piping only `stdout`.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


def waitForAppOutput(proc, word):
    for stdout_line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ''):
       print stdout_line
       if word in stdout_line.rstrip():
          return;

p = Popen("./app.sh", shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
expected_input = "command line 1\ncommand line 2\n"
p.stdin.write(expected_input)
p.stdin.close()
waitForAppOutput(p, "done!")
for stdout_line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
    pass # read rest of output
p.wait() # wait for termination
```

**Update**

Here is an example using both techniques that runs the Windows `sort` command to sort a bunch of input lines. This works particularly well both ways because the sort command does not start output until all the input has been read, so it's a very simple protocol in which deadlocking is easy to avoid. Try running this with `USE_COMMUNICATE` set alternately to `True` and `False`:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

USE_COMMUNICATE = False

p = Popen("sort", shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
expected_input = """q
w
e
r
t
y
u
i
o
p
"""
if USE_COMMUNICATE:
    stdout_lines, stderr_lines = p.communicate(expected_input)
    output = stdout_lines
else:
    p.stdin.write(expected_input)
    p.stdin.close()
    output = iter(p.stdout.readline, '')
for stdout_line in output:
    print stdout_line,
p.wait() # wait for termination
```

Prints:

```
e
i
o
p
q
r
t
u
w
y
```

Comment: you right, it was a typo in the post that i have fixed. as for you solution - what happen if i call p.communicate() before the desired output was printed to stdout? it is going to work?

Comment: `p.communicate()` waits for the process to complete and returns whatever output has been piped to stdout and/or stderr (you can also pass an argument, which is the data to be sent to `stdin.pipe`, but that is not applicable in your case). I wouldn't have posted this if I didn't think it would work, so why don't you just try it.

Comment: i tried, it look like it does not returns from p.communicate(). the issue here is that the app is not terminated by itself after "done!" is printed, the app CLI waits for input.

Comment: You would need to *show* the app to fully understand what you are talking about. But re-read my last comment and look up documentation for `communicate`. Specify on `Popen` additionally `stdin=PIPE` and pass as the argument to `communicate` a byte string that is the input your app is expecting to read (it can be multiple lines separated by '\n').

Comment: By the way, if you specify on `Popen`, `text=True`, then instead of passing and getting out byte strings, you pass and get out standard (unicode) strings.

Comment: from "communicate()" docs - "Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate" my app not terminates so i dont see how it can help.
as for your second suggestion, im using python 2.7 and it seems like the "text" filed not supported =/

Comment: For Python 2, instead of '`text=True`, specify `universal_newlines=True`. Your app is not terminating because you are now saying that it is waiting for input, which is something you had never said in your original post, **right?** So I now repeat again: **You have to pass to `communicate` all the input that the app is expecting to receive that will cause it to terminate.** Do you understand this?

Comment: I have updated answer to give an example of using `stdin=PIPE` with sample input.

Comment: `communicate()` is not the right solution if you want the process to run in parallel and shut it down as soon as it produces the output you are looking for. But the OP's code has several obvious bugs so this should probably simply be closed as unclear.

Comment: @tripleee I don't think the OP wants to shut it down as soon as it produces a certain output; I think the OP wants it to complete normally but only wants to print output up until `done!` is printed. Anyway, that is my interpretation and that is what I am attempting. And clearly `communicate` blocks until the process completes. So what?  It's also pretty late in the game to find out the process requires certain input to terminate and we still haven't heard what that is.